# browser-caching works except for svg-images

Tags: .htaccess, caching, svg

I'm having trouble with the browser-caching of SVG-files.

In my .htaccess, everything seems to be fine (at least it is rather complete) but no matter what I try, it seems as if the SVG-images aren't making their way into the browser's cache.

there's

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ...
    (various other file-types)
    ...
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

in the .htaccess, I tried

```
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
```

too, but nothing works. I also tried to change the mime-type to text/svg+xml. no good neither.

What could cause this failure?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check in the response header that the svg you get is seen as a "image/svg+xml" ?

Comment: Hi Val! Yes, it says «content-type: Image/svg+xml» (and the request-header means under «Pragma / Cache-Control: no-cache») it would be great if the was a hint to the source of the problem...

Comment: It is freaky to see `Image/svg+xml` with an uppercase "I" in your response. I don't know if mime-types are case sensitive or not. It is probably not the cause of your problem (because in the worst case your svg file should be catch by the `ExpiresDefault`...) but you can try to add an `expiresByType Image/svg+xml` ... 
Do you have a `AddType  image/svg+xml .svg` directive ? 
Did you take a look in the apache modules to see if there are other rules for svg files ?

Comment: I must admit I am near my wits end… I suspect there's something with the .htaccess, and not apache's configuration. So I swapped my .htaccess with a default bootstrap.htaccess and voila! no more cache-complaints…

Comment: I had a similar scenario, but didn't have ExpiresActive on set. ExpiresDefault was working for all file types except svg. Adding ExpiresActive on made it work for svg as well. But I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the suggestion by @Ariel I checked my .conf files and I keep having the same issue, although I added

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault  "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg  "access plus 1 month"
```

even if it is working (i assume) for svg fonts. I have no .htaccess, so everything is done in the .conf files. On that note i also have

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|css|js|swf)$">
     Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
```

but as far as i know that wouldn't even touch the svg files. Thanks